# Get Primary key id with Column filter in Django ORM

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, orm, django-orm

I have a table **books** in my Postgresql. The below image is how the table structure looks.

[image]

Now, I have the book_name "**249**", and I want to get its corresponding primary key which is 5. Below is the query I am trying to do but Django is throwing an error.

my_book_name = 249

```
books.model.filter(book_name=my_book_name).get('book_id') # Not Working
```

Can someone please suggest the right ORM query for getting the corresponding book_id for book_name?

**Note**:- I deleted PK=4 which is why it's missing in the Column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.values(..)` here:

```
Books.objects.values('book_id').get(book_name=my_book_name)['book_id']
```

But using `.values(..)` is often not a good idea. Typically you fetch a `Book` *object* into memory, like:

```
book = Books.objects.get(book_name=my_book_name)
book.book_id  # 5
```

But even then, it is possible that multiple books (or no books at all) have that name. So you should use `.filter(..)` to obtain a `QuerySet` of `Book`s. A `QuerySet` is a *lazy* collection, and thus can contain zero, one, or more `Book` objects here:

```
books = Books.objects.filter(book_name=my_book_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you are using get with filter! Try this

```
books.objects.filter(book_name=my_book_name).values('book_id')
```

This will return book_id for all the entries having book_name=my_book_name

Comment: Thanks buddy!.. and BTW it should be "books.objects.filter" and not "books.model.filter"